# Comparing Similar Hive Tables

Tags: hadoop, compare, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I have two hive tables (t1 and t2) that I would like to compare. The second table has 5 additional columns that are not in the first table. Other than the five disjoint fields, the two tables should be identical. I am trying to write a query to check this. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
UNION ALL
select * from t2
GROUP BY some_value
HAVING count(*) == 2
```

If the tables are identical, this should return 0 records. However, since the second table contains 5 extra fields, I need to change the second select statement to reflect this. There are almost 60 column names so I would really hate to write it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
UNION ALL
select field1, field2, field3,...,fieldn from t2
GROUP BY some_value
HAVING count(*) == 2
```

I have looked around and I know there is no `select * EXCEPT` syntax, but is there a way to do this query without having to explicity name each column that I want included in the final result?

Comment: Won't all of the records in your first query have a count == 2? Each row will be duplicated if the tables are identical. UNION ALL does not remove any duplicates.

Comment: yes, you are correct. The result should have the same count as the original number of rows

Answer (score 0):

You should have used `UNION DISTINCT` for the logic you are applying.

However, the number and names of columns returned by each `select_statement` have to be the same otherwise a schema error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this Python program that handles such comparisons of Hive tables (comparing all the rows and all the columns), and would show you in a webpage the differences that might appear: https://github.com/bolcom/hive_compared_bq

To skip the 5 extra fields, you could use the "--ignore-columns" option.